FlowScoped Faces configuration issue in WebSphere Application Server V9
I'm attempting to run a Java EE 7 Cargo Tracker on tWAS 9 and have encountered a Faces configuration issue. I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.
The application uses Faces 2.2, and I've observed that the FlowScoped bean fails to initialize, resulting in a NullPointerException. The flow structure is as follows:
booking
  - booking-date.xhtml
  - booking-destination.xhtml
  - booking-flow.xml
  - booking.xhtml 

The application fails to initialize. However, if I remove the flow configuration file (booking-flow.xml), all parts of the application except the flow work fine.
The flow works fine in Glassfish.
Here are some logs:
[5/29/24 7:56:18:614 UTC]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -RE ProbeId:1123 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@b63c8f93
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider.getModule(WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider.java:224)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(WASMyFacesAnnotationProvider.java:135)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.AnnotationConfigurator.createFacesConfig(AnnotationConfigurator.java:92)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.getAnnotationsFacesConfig(DefaultFacesConfigurationProvider.java:200)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.getFacesConfigData(DefaultFacesConfigurationMerger.java:91)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:600)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.update(FacesConfigurator.java:505)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:137)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:198)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1408)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:198)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:682)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4238)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.handleRequest(WebAppImpl.java:2210)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1033)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)

Could you please advise on how to diagnose and resolve this issue?
